# What happens if I don't call willMoveToParentViewController & didMoveToParentViewController explicitly?

Tags: ios, containers, viewcontroller

XCode Document says 
If you are implementing your own container view controller, it must call the `willMoveToParentViewController:` method of the child view controller before calling the `removeFromParentViewController` method, passing in a parent value of nil.
and
If you are implementing your own container view controller, it must call the `didMoveToParentViewController:` method of the child view controller after the transition to the new controller is complete or, if there is no transition, immediately after calling the `addChildViewController:` method.

What will happen I don't call willMoveToParentViewController & didMoveToParentViewController explicitly??

Comment: @rmaddy I've wrote some test code leaving out the required function and it  seems to work without any problem

Answer (score 1):

`-willMoveToParentViewController` and `-didMoveToParentViewController` call the `UIViewController`'s `-viewWillAppear` and `-viewDidAppear` methods respectively. If you leave these calls out, the former methods will not be called.

Comment: I call `[self addChildViewController:child]` and `[self.view addSubview:child.view]` in parentViewController, it seems child's `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` will be called automatically.